# Libcurl - curl_multi_info_read - ошибка доступа

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

Подскажите пожалуйста, из за чего ошибка доступа получается при обращении к полю структуры CURLMsg:

Вот простенький код, который я и использую:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl.h>

int main()
{

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);


    CURL* curl;

    if (curl == CURL_OK) 
    {
        CURLcode curl_easy_setopt_status;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.cyberforum.com"); //сайт с заведомо некорректным сертификатом

        curl_easy_setopt_status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  //Установка редиректа

        curl_easy_setopt_status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);   //Установка кол-ва редиректов



        curl_easy_setopt_status = curl_easy_setopt(CURL_p, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1); 
        curl_easy_setopt_status = curl_easy_setopt(CURL_p, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1); 



    //Запуск http-запроса: ------->

   

        CURLM* multi_handle;
        CURLMcode CURLMcode_;
        int still_running = 0;
    
        multi_handle = curl_multi_init();
    
        curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, curl);
    
        CURLMcode_ = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
    
    
        CURLMsg* my_CURLMsg_multi_info_read;   //Структура возвращаемая функцией curl_multi_info_read.
        int my_msgs_in_queue_int;         
    
    
        while (still_running != 0)
        {
    
            CURLMcode_ = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
    
            if (CURLMcode_ == 0)
            {
                CURLMcode_ = curl_multi_poll(multi_handle, NULL, 0, 1000, NULL);
            }
            else
            {
             break;
            }
    
    
            my_CURLMsg_multi_info_read = curl_multi_info_read(multi_handle, &my_msgs_in_queue_int); //Запрашиваю структуру CURLMsg.
    
             if (my_CURLMsg_multi_info_read != 0) //Если указатель действительный, то:
             {
                    if (my_CURLMsg_multi_info_read->msg == CURLMSG_DONE)
                    {
              //Теперь пытаюсь обратится к первому байту поля whatever:
    
              std::cout << "whatever_address:" << my_CURLMsg_multi_info_read->data.whatever <<std::endl;   //АДРЕСС НЕ НУЛЕВОЙ, то есть указатель действительный.
    
              std::cout << "whatever:" << ((char*)(*my_CURLMsg_multi_info_read).data.whatever)[0] << std::endl;  //ТУТ я терплю ОШИБКУ ДОСТУПА! Почему же так?
                    }
              }
    
        } 
    
        
    
    
        return 0;
}
```

Сама структура CURLMSG выглядит так:

```
struct CURLMsg 
        {
            CURLMSG msg;       // what this message means == CURLMSG_DONE
            CURL* easy_handle; // the handle it concerns
            union 
            {
                void* whatever;    // message-specific data
                CURLcode result;   // return code for transfer
            } data;
        };
```

Если полю whatever - указателю на void - присвоен адрес, то значит хотя бы доступ к 1 байту, то я должен иметь, почему ошибка доступа то получается ?

Comment: Код напоминает взрыв на макаронной фабрике...

Comment: @user7860670, а можете подсказать, что по Вашему мнению там напоминает взрыв ? Если весь код, то хотя бы пару моментов, которые вам не нравятся ?

Comment: Огромное количество лишних переносов строк и прыгающие отступы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When msg is CURLMSG_DONE, the message identifies a transfer that is done, and then result contains the return code for the easy handle that just completed.

Соответственно поле `whatever` не активно и обращение к нему влечет UB.

И даже если указателю на void присвоен адрес, то это совсем не значит, что этот адрес валидный, или что по нему есть доступ хотя бы к 1 байту

Comment: Не могу понять, как из описания CURLMSG_DONE - следует, то, что whatever - неактивен ? И даже непонятно другое, как физически возможно, что void* содержит адрес, но к этому адресу нельзя обратится. Курл туда просто поместил какой то рандомный адрес что ли, который ему не принадлежит ? Если да, то зачем, почему бы просто не передать нулевой указатель.

Comment: @Optimus1 Там же прямо написано - `result contains the return code`. А `whatever` и `result` внутри union, а не структуры.

Comment: все равно не понимаю, как наличие данных в result - отрицает наличие валидного указателя в whatever ? Да result Содержит код возврата, но, как это отрицает, что указатель в whatever - не валидный ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Потому что они внутри union, а не структуры. В union может быть активно не более одного поля. И когда там используется поле result, то к whatever обращаться нельзя.

Comment: спасибо! Теперь понял, не знал такой нюанс про union.